# Is it possible to use client certificates to identify a single workstation to a web site?

Tags: windows, webserver, certificate

Basically, I need to uniquely identify a client PC from an intranet webserver for all users that log on. I am considering reliable methods of doing this and am currently considering using client identity certificates. A new certificate would be issued for each workstation that needs to connect to the site. The site would track which certificates were assigned to which machine.

Is it possible to specify a single certificate for a machine that then gets sent to IIS as an identity?

While the web-server will be running Windows, it would be nice if there was a multi-platform solution for the clients.

Thanks for any help

Comment: If you are on the intranet then you can identfy clients by their MAC Address ssince you have 100% control over the network.

Answer (score 0):

Client keys are used to identify entities. This could also be a computer.

Please think about adding some more check than the certificate alone as the key can be copied to another computer.